# Weird issue while using IBDesignable UILabel class

Tags: ios, swift3

I am facing a weird issue when I try to use the custom UILabel that I have designed. The view is visible in the storyboard and its working fine with properties. Now What I have done is in my Designable class i have set a property called `isError` which when set, I need to append an * at the start of my text.

But as soon as in my code I do that, My Designable properties are not used and the Label is not correctly shown on the device and it takes the default properties of UILabel without adding * to the text. Not sure where I am going wrong.

**Custom Label Code**

```
@IBDesignable class KGIBDesignableLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var verticalPad: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var horizontalPad: CGFloat = 0
    var isError: Bool = false{
        didSet {
            setup()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
    }


    func setup(){
        if isError{
            text="*"+text!;
            textColor = UIColor.KGColorPalette.errorMessageColor
        }else{
            textColor = UIColor.KGColorPalette.textEntryLabelColor
            text=text!;
        }

        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        clipsToBounds = true
        textAlignment = .center
        numberOfLines = 0
        lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        sizeToFit()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let superSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let newWidth = superSize.width + superSize.height + (2 * horizontalPad)
        let newHeight = superSize.height + (2 * verticalPad)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

**Access code in VC**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCustom: KGIBDesignableLabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        labelCustom.isError=true
        // After adding this^ line it takes default UILabel properties
    }
```

Comment: you need to call again setup method after change value if isError

Comment: The change of Value is inside the setup method itself? It might go recursive.

Comment: Plus i tried doing that in the didSet method of the variable. It did add the * to the text but then the size of the label went haywire and it split the text into multiple lines even though there was space for more

Comment: @kapsym check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Mistake** calling `setup` in your `layoutSubview` method cause a consecutive calling from `setup` to `layoutSubview` because you are modifying things in the `setup` that cause `layoutSubview` is called

**Fix** Remove your `setup` method from `layoutSubviews()`

**Second Mistake** calling `sizeToFit()` in your `setup` adjust the size of your text to the current size before calculate your intrinsic content size

**Fix** remove the `sizeToFit()` from your `setup`

**Third Mistake** you were setting as `width` the `label.intrinsicSize.width + label.intrinsicSize.height + (2 * horizontalPad)` is obvious that height is wrong there

**Fix** replace this line `let newWidth = superSize.width + superSize.height + (2 * horizontalPad)` by this one `let newWidth = superSize.width + (2 * horizontalPad)

your code **modified** and **working**

```
@IBDesignable class KGIBDesignableLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var verticalPad: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var horizontalPad: CGFloat = 0
    var isError: Bool = false{
        didSet {
            setup()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
    }


    func setup(){
        if isError{
            text="*"+text!;
            textColor = UIColor.red
        }else{
            textColor = UIColor.black
            text=text!;
        }

        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        clipsToBounds = true
        textAlignment = .center
        numberOfLines = 0
        lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let superSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let newWidth = superSize.width + (2 * horizontalPad)
        let newHeight = superSize.height + (2 * verticalPad)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

this is how it looks with 10 and 10 as values por vertical and horizontal padding

[image]

hope this helps

Comment: It does help to show the * but then my text gets split into multiple line even though the value of the text is just "Label" it shows *Lab in one line and el in another.

Comment: @kapsym i will check your setup method

Comment: @kapsym why you implement intrinsic content size? UILabel have an intrinsic content size by default, and i think your subclass only add a * in error or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes for now it add * and i implemented intrinsic content size to adjust the padding from the sides. I am new to designing custom Designables so i might be wrong at a lot of places.

Comment: Awesome man this helps exactly i needed. Could you throw in some light on why these were causing issues so that i dont do the same mistake again.

Comment: @kapsym added explanation, if i have some gramatical errors please edit my answer, i am not english native speaker

Comment: Thanks this helps